# Unable to obtain content from website using Hpple

Tags: iphone, html-parsing

I was trying to parse from a website using HPPLE. I was successful with the  tag but it doesn't seem to work on the other tag.  Please advice.

This was the code that I used.

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/"]];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//tr/td"];
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myTitle = [element content];
NSLog(myTitle);
mLabel.text = myTitle;
[xpathParser release];
[htmlData release];
```

This is the website source code that I was trying to parse from.

```
<tr><td bgcolor="#f7f7f7" align="left" width="200" valign="middle" class="font1">Title of Speech</td><td bgcolor="#f7f7f7" align="left" width="150" valign="middle" class="font3">Speaker Name</td><td bgcolor="#f7f7f7" align="left" width="150" valign="middle" class="font3">Date and Time</td><td bgcolor="#f7f7f7" align="center" width="50" valign="middle" class="font3"><a href=""><a href="http://speech.mp4" target="blank"><img src="/Templates/public/images/mp4_300.png" border="0" /></a></a></td
```

I was intending to parse out the Speech Title, Speaker, Date and Time and name of the mp4 file. But it return a empty string to my outlet label.  Please advice.

Regards, Des

Answer (score 1):

Late but maybe useful for others:

Use

```
NSString *myTitle = [element text];
```

instead of `content`

I used hpple for getting the `<title>`-Tag of some websites. `content` was empty but not `text`.